# jquery sticky sidebar working second scroll

Tags: sticky, firefox-sidebar

I have this page:
[click here to see my apge](http://www.longnecklaces.com/productsFake.php)

my problem is that the sticky sidebar works but it does not work the first time I scroll, can anybody help with this problem? I have no idea why it doesn't work the first time I scroll down.
Thanks